# Trigger for 1:m relationship

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have 2 tables: customers and orders. How can I use trigger to create 1:M relationship?

I have next tables

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    customer_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    customer_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    datachange TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
);


CREATE TABLE Orders(
    order_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY(order_id)
);
```

And I have to do a trigger instead of:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders add constraint FK_CUSTOMER_ID FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(customer_id);
```

Comment: Relation for what?
What do you seek to achieve?

Comment: I have in orders customer_id column, I have to create trigger on it for 1:M relationship

Comment: Can you post an example of what lies in the table and what you want to get?

Comment: I have next tables
`
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    customer_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    customer_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    datachange TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
);


CREATE TABLE Orders(
    order_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY(order_id)
);
`

And I have to do a trigger instead of:

ALTER TABLE Orders add constraint FK_CUSTOMER_ID FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(customer_id);

Comment: I've updated main question with formatting

Comment: you mean, you want to create an index when data is inserted into orders table?

Comment: No, I need to make relation by  trigger
I guess this trigger will be called once after creating table

Comment: What is the requirement of creating a foreign key relation with trigger? Is it not insane?
I believe relations are part of database design.
Even if you create a trigger, would it not fire the trigger every time you insert a row?

Comment: just university task, idk, that's why ask about help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example how to create a trigger:
https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/

but relation is the best solution at this moment:
[image: relation]

if there is no specific reason to complicate something, don't complicate it. Use simple and widely used solutions to avoid many problems in the future :-)

ps. I'm not sure if you are using MySQL or some other database because you didn't specify ...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [trigger syntax](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx). It clearly mentions

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
{BEFORE | AFTER} {INSERT | UPDATE| DELETE }
ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
trigger_body;
```

Can't find any trigger on `CREATE TABLE`.

Can you properly explain why the trigger needs to be fired after you create table?
Maybe you are misunderstanding the functions of a trigger